# Skipping song when there is no up next song

Tags: discord.js, distube

Regarding Distube v3 in DJS v13, skipping song is poping errors when there is no up next song in the queue. The code that I was using in Distube v2 is no longer compacted to v3. I have made some adjustment based on v3 update, I would like to ask if anyone have any clues on skipping song when there is no up next song in the queue.

```js
    const queue = client.distube.getQueue(message)
    if (!queue) return message.channel.send(`**There is nothing playing in the queue now!**`)
    try {
        await queue.skip();
        message.channel.send('**Skipped** :track_next:');
        return;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it with my bot is to check whether the autoplay is off and queue length is 1 then call the stop method otherwise call skip.

This should solve your problem:

```
if (!queue.autoplay && queue.songs.length == 1)
    queue.stop();
else
    queue.skip();
```

Comment: I have consider this solution as well. After checking back my coding, I use stop method to disconnect the bot. If I want to skip the song when there is no up next song, using stop method will disconnect the bot. Consider changing leaveOnStop to false will disable my current disconnect command. Any clue on balancing and solving this issue?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the "leaveOnStop" setting is set to false. By "disconnect command" do you mean a command to kick the bot from the voice channel ? Cuz it doesn't make sense this setting to cause trouble to it.

Comment: yes a command to kick the bot fron channel. I use stop method to kick it, is there anyway to kick the bot out of the vc so that i can apply the stop method on skipping song?

Comment: I think it's better to have your own command to kick the bot and not depend on Distube. To do that you will need to get the voice connection with getVoiceConnection(guild_id) and if it's not null call it's method destroy(). Note that getVoiceConnection requires "@discordjs/voice".